# Is the computational basis for Hilbert space transfinite?

Tags: mathematics

In [What is the Computational Basis?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1410/2645) gIS states:

> One also often speaks of "computational basis" for higher-dimensional states (qudits), in which case the same applies: a basis is called "computational" when it's the most "natural" in a given context.

The Wikipedia page for [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) includes this snippet:

> When that set of axes is countably infinite, the Hilbert space can also be usefully thought of in terms of the space of infinite sequences that are square-summable. The latter space is often in the older literature referred to as *the* Hilbert space.

**If *the* Hilbert space has countably infinite axes, is the computational basis for it transfinite?**

<strike>Additionally, would it be accurate to state that computations with finite bases correlate to classical computations, while computations with transfinite bases correlate quantum computations?</strike>

Comment: Please, have a look at my answer on PSE of the following question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90004/separability-axiom-really-necessary/90116#90116 (and of course the other answers).

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe Awesome! "The infinite tensor product of harmonic oscillators" & "continuous tensor products" are both very interesting to me. Do you have any suggestions on further reading?

Comment: You can start with these introductory lectures by Averson: https://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/Dvi/prodsys.pdf and Vershik http://www.math.columbia.edu/department/Igor60/talks/vi-vershik.pdf. Further material in Averson: https://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/oldDvi/endoqftsurvey.pdf and Veshik and Tsilevich https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304282. This subject is heavily mathematical.

Comment: Please see also Gavriel Segre's thesis where he comments on the issue of separability from the quantum information point of view: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0110018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a finite basis for $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ if you have n qubits. Finite basis (with cardinality $2^n$)-still quantum.

$\mathcal{H}$ could be countably infinite dimensional. Like $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$ for an orbital. Or an anti-symmetric combination of $N$ of those denoted $\wedge^N (L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3))$ for $N$ electrons in some molecule. Both countable dimensional.

The set of states is uncountable, but that is just like saying $\mathbb{C}$ or the set of phases $e^{i \theta}$ is uncountable as a set. True but not really relevant because you are using other structure besides just being a set.

Uncountable dimensional Hilbert spaces are hairier. They would not be separable so a bunch of theorems you need would disappear.

Edit: Was referring to orthogonal basis not algebraic basis. If you demanded everything written as a finite linear combinations of basis vectors then the sequence $e_i$ of vectors that have $1$ in position $i$ and 0's elsewhere would not be a basis for $\ell^2 (\mathbb{N})$. You would need infinitely many of them for something like $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\cdots)$. So to make an algebraic basis you would need more basis vectors, in fact uncountably more. Another way to see this is the set of $(1,t,t^2,\cdots)$ for all $0<t<1$ is uncountable and algebraically linearly independent so algebraically $\ell^2 (\mathbb{N})$ is at least uncountably infinite dimensional in the algebraic sense. In a Hilbert space usually using Hilbert space dimension not vector space dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am unfamiliar w/ [$L^2$ space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html) & anti-symmetric (tensor?) combinations. I was able to find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285247/564236) regarding "uncountable dimensional Hilbert space(s)" (Google returns less than 5 results ..); is it possible you could potentially elaborate further on this point or give me a hint in which direction to continue investigating?

Comment: I was using orthogonal basis for counting. Noah's answer there uses a different purely algebraic sense of the word basis. If you're in a Hilbert space, you usually use the orthogonality because you have that extra structure.

Comment: Will look more into [Hilbert space vs. vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/does-there-exist-a-real-hilbert-space-with-countably-infinite-dimension-as-a-vec/17629#comment4653022_2261286)! [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17627/564236) also is interesting (re: "real" Hilbert space).

Comment: You should probably stay on the Hilbert space side of that vs. You can see how you're running into weird pathologies.